# Не могу подключить main.min.js к HTML странице

Tags: javascript, gulp

Не могу подключить main.min.js к HTML странице. Собрал проект через Gulp, возможно это из-за него ошибка какая-то, ведь без него, тот же код работает без ошибок.
В исходном коде если нажать на подключенный .js пишет - Cannot GET /dist/assets/js/main.min.js
Как подключить его, в последствии чтобы он еще и работал?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

99% что проблема в путях после сборки.
Для чего указываете папку `dist` и тем более относительно корня?
В неё копируются уже модифицированные файлы, поэтому пути должны быть относительно неё т.е. скорей  всего без: `/dist/`

путь должен быть таким:

```
<script src="assets/js/main.min.js"></script>
```

при этом в папке `src` у вас тоже должен быть файл `assets/js/main.js` (только не минифицированный)